# Populate a html div with json data received from a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, json-rpc

I need to have a html div populated with the json data received from the server which is a json-rpc server and it retruns an application/jsson-rpc content type and i can see the result in the chrome and firefox dev tools... I need to view it as part of the page inside a given div

i have this script to populate the mybox div but it gives nothing

```
    var returnedinfo;
    var request = $.ajax ({
    url: "/url",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(json) {
      alert("success sent ajax");
         $("#mybox").html(json); 
         returnedinfo = json;               
   });
```

I also tied having the populating function outside the ajax block when the request is done

```
request.done(function(msg) {
         $("#mybox").text(msg);
       });
```

This just return an empty array like this

```
 [object Object]
```

and nothing else help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the format of json.

Comment: use `dataType:"json"`

Comment: what do you mean by format of json? and is'nt the datatype json supposed to be for the sent POST request?

Comment: this is a common issue you could have seen how to do on multiple blogs and even this website if you bothered to google

Comment: @GideonMaina use console.log(josn) and see what is returning from server

Comment: Anoop console.log is giving me what i need succesfully

Comment: please post that data here..

Comment: Anoop solved it by adding the dotobject as this (json.result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to append the `key` of the json item.

```
$("#mybox").html(json.key);
```

Comment: Thanks Levent it works now after i append the key of the json item i needed like $("#mybox").html(json.result);

Answer (score 1):

Add dataType to your ajax request.

```
var request = $.ajax ({
url: "/url",
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(data),
dataType: "json",
success: function(json) {
  alert("success sent ajax");
     $("#mybox").html(json); 
     returnedinfo = json;               
});
```

Comment: What did you see for console.log(josn).
Can you provide your Response json?

Answer (score 1):

try this my working example
look *contentType* and `html` function to replace html of mybox element

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'url',
    success: function (dataRes) {
                $('#mybox').html(dataRes);

              },
    error: function(a,b,c) {

    }
});
```

Note that in this case *dataRes* in success function is an html string like `<strong>test</strong>`. 
 
If your server side function returns a json object you should add  `dataType: 'json'` to ajax request and then you can use properties of *dataRes* object like here `$('#mybox').html(dataRes.property1);`